# Beginning android developer problems

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device, android-2.2-froyo

I'm a beginning programmer and have just started using Android Studio in order to learn the basic of the basic of Android Studio. However, I am unable (it seems) to set up a permanent AVD (Android Virtual Device) in order to test any projects I am working on. Additionally, whenever I try to run a program, I get an error message in the "Error/Debug Configurations" dialogue box that pops up that reads "Error: Please select Android SDK". I know this is a vague question, but any pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated!

Comment: It may not be ideal to use a beta IDE when you're only just learning Android.

Comment: You might want to check out this udacity course, it goes over creating an AVD in Android Studio. https://www.udacity.com/course/ud853

Comment: Here are work around steps to help fix the "Error: Please select Android SDK" : https://stackoverflow.com/a/45865789/3853712

Answer (score 0):

Setup a virtual device :

```
Tools > Android > AVD Manager
```

I believe this works for android studio

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you installed Android Studio without any sdk, and Android Studio does need it.

Try downloading and installing the Android Studio Bundle from here: https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html

Answer (score 0):

On the left panel of android studio, select the app 
Then press F4 which will take you to the project structure,
Select the SDK location, or download one if you dont have.