# Android SDK found - Android Studio 2.0 beta 5

Tags: android-studio, google-api, android-sdk-tools

I am using latest version of Android Studio 2.0 Beta 5 with Android SDK 24.4.1 and Android Build Tool 23.0.2.

I am facing one issue when I try to compile with Google APIs like this compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:23' in app level build.gradle.

I am getting error No Android SDK found. Please configure an Android SDK in design preview and Preview Android Version is  There is no list to select any Android OS Version.

I am unable to RUN app because it shows error in Edit Configuration. This is the Error: Please select Android SDK.

If I change *compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:23'* to **compileSdkVersion 23** every thing works fine.

I also checked with Tools (Preview Channel) Android SDK tools 25.0.6 after downloading but same issue.

This bug was also in 2.0 beta 2, beta 3, beta 4 and still I am facing.

It was working fine before Android Studio 2.0

Please let me know What should I do?

Comment: I'm having the same issue in Android Studio 2.1.1. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Right now I am using Android Studio 2.1.1  Android SDK Tools 25.1.6   Android SDK Platform-tools 24 rc3  Android SDK Build-tools 24rc4  Android API 23  and Its working fine. Are you having issue on MAC ?

Comment: Yes, on a Mac. I found that simply renaming the sdk folder, and updating the path in Android studio solved the issue!?!

Comment: If this issue comes up again for me I'll try to rename sdk folder but somehow now its working fine for me.

Comment: same here: "If I change compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:23' to compileSdkVersion 23 every thing works fine."

Comment: Andronicus' solution worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to comments, I did solve the issue by applying a 'rename back and forth' technique on the <android_sdks_folder>:

1. **Stop** Android Studio
2. **Rename** *<android_sdks_folder>* to *<android_sdks_folder>**_2***
3. **Restart** Android Studio and set *<android_sdks_folder>**_2*** as new SDK path 
   (in Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings -> Android SDK : select *'SDK Platforms'* tab)

This solved the

> If I change compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:23' to
>   compileSdkVersion 23 every thing works fine.

issue for me: Now I can choose 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:23', as well as '23' and both work fine :-)

Now if you want your setup to be as before, just repeat the operations but rename folder back to original: i.e.:

1. Stop Android Studio
2. Rename *<android_sdks_folder>**_2*** to *<android_sdks_folder>*
3. Start Android Studio and set *<android_sdks_folder>* as new SDK path

You're now good to go with a standard setup :)

*Note:*
On windows, I use to start Android Studio ***as admin*** as it makes it avoid some standard issue (just Google for it)

Comment: I find I don't need to mess about renaming the sdk folder - just tell Android Studio to use the same folder - somehow it loses the config on a new repo.   See this thread for more discussion:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/45865789/3853712

Comment: @JimAndreas I tried your solution at the time, but it didn't work. That's why I ended up doing my proposed solution: works every time. Thanks.