# I got following error when importing project in Intellij Idea (Community Edition) 2016.2.1 EAP

Tags: android, intellij-idea

The Logcat shows the following error :-

```
 Error:(18, 1) A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
```

> SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties    file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.

I have search out for this but don't find local.properties .
Can anyone solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID\_HOME environment variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27620262/sdk-location-not-found-define-location-with-sdk-dir-in-the-local-properties-fil)

Comment: But in Inetllij Idea 2016.2.1 don't find .local properties

Comment: The `local.properties` file goes in the project's root level, in the same folder as the `gradlew`, `gradlew.bat`, `settings.gradle` and other files.

Comment: there is not any file  with that name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error says it all

Your local.properties file should contain, in my case this line

```
sdk.dir=C\:\\Users\\johnrao\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk
```

Comment: But in Inetllij Idea 2016.2.1 don't find .local properties.Where is this file?

Comment: if you don't , then create one inside your project diectory

Comment: Can you please tell me how to create it.

Comment: open your fav text editor , paste that line, edit it to point to your sdk..then save it as local.properties, then paste it in your project directory

Comment: sdk.dir=C\:\\Users\\hp-\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk my sdk is this and I do all you say but still shows an error

Comment: try setting ANDROID_HOME environment variable then

Comment: thanks It works actually I copied the file at wrong location.Now I changed the location  so It works

Answer (score 0):

As your Error say that

> SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the
>   local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable

to solve it you have to create it.

> Note : This file in automatically createed. but as you can say that
>   the file is not found. Then you have create it .

The `local.properties` file goes in the project's root level, in the same folder as the `gradlew`, `gradlew.bat`, `settings.gradle` and other files.

in `local.properties` contain this thing.

```
sdk.dir=C\:\\Program Files (x86)\\Android\\android-studio\\sdk
```

> **Note :** the sdk.dir= reference to the location of the Android Studio
>   SDK installation (which may be different on different machines