# 'SDK Location not found' in Android Studio despite having the environment variable set correctly

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools

I am a little confused why I am getting this message when the ANDROID_HOME environment variable is actually set.

[image]

It is also set in project defaults:
[image]

I am probably missing something trivial here, but not sure what. Thanks

Comment: refere this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/24600635/4684984

Comment: Personally, I think it's some bug on Android Studio (and Intellij) that it does not pickup environment variables on a Mac. The `local.properties`  file fixes the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your local.properties file

If **sdk.dir="Your sdk path"** is not available in the file. Please add it and try.

Comment: This file did not exist and I had to add it, but the message implies that it can bew EITHER be that file or the environment variable so I don't understand why that should be necessary. Do you know?

Comment: You could edit your other answer. Instead of posting a second one

Comment: You should define sdk path in your local.properties file and also in the Android SDK home path.

Comment: If local.properties file is not available please create it

Answer (score 7):

Faced the same issue with **Intellij IDEA 2017.2** on **MacOS Sierra**. 
I have two projects with different Build targets (26 and 25).
Both projects were created on Win and committed to Git.

The First cloned project was with Build target 26. All needed SDK platforms and tools were downloaded with SDK Manager. The project compiled and built without any errors.
I didn't set up ANDROID_HOME variable or create local.properties file. I just set up the "Android SDK home path" within IDEA.
[image: Android SDK home path field]

The Second cloned project was with Build target 25. I downloaded all needed SDK platforms and tools for this target. Then I configured new SDK for the Android API 25 platform. On Build APK got the error **"SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable"**. I tried many solutions (created ANDROID_HOME, re-installed SDK, changed settings many times) except local.properties creation - nothing works for me. As I use the same project on different platforms the creation of the local.properties file is not a good choice.

Today I made a strange thing. I clicked the **Edit** link near the **Android SDK Location field** in the SDK Manager. Then **Next -> Next -> Finish**.
[image: Android SDK Location Edit]

And my issue gone.

Comment: This worked for me with Android Studio 3.3 running El Capitan. Thank you! Thank you! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should also change it on Project Structure.

Close the current project and you'll see pop up with dialog which will then proceed to Configure option.

**Configure -> Project Defaults -> Project Structure -> SDKs on left column -> Android SDK Home Path ->** give the exact path as you did on local.properties and select Valid Target.

Comment: Thanks but project defaults are set properly as well. See update.

Answer (score 0):

You should define sdk path in your local.properties file and also in the Android SDK home path.

local.properties file is not available in your project. Please add it **Gradle scripts** and give the sdk path to **sdk.dir**

It will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please check correct sdk path in your local.properties file and also in the Android SDK home path.

If still not successful, You have to just copy your local.properties file to the folder where project is stored and it will work. But remember, it must be placed in the root folder where the project is stored.