# Error SDK when opening Telegram project with Android Studio

Tags: api, android-studio, sdk, project, telegram

I get an error when loading the project. I have downloaded the TMessagesProj from official site (https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram). I excute android studio, open the project and i get an error "SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable" I have check local.properties file and everything is correct, the SDK is updated, and i got no idea what to do. Should anybody help me?...thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID\_HOME environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27620262/sdk-location-not-found-define-location-with-sdk-dir-in-the-local-properties-fil)

Comment: thanks but, i check that issue before write my question...in the setting.gradle seems to be all right.

Comment: ...and my local.properties is storaged at the project folder.

Comment: When you read a similar question, you can write in your question that you have already  read this question and it doesn't help you for some reason