# Android studio SDK problems with Mac and Windows cross

Tags: android, macos

[image: Problem]

Sorry for asking but, I have recently been using drive to save my projects in sync from a mac computer to a windows one. My project file on android studio started on my windows file but the sdk location and files were changed to suit the mac. When I try to open it on windows it says it changed the SDK directory as shown in the image but the project still is not functional

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27620262/sdk-location-not-found-define-location-with-sdk-dir-in-the-local-properties-fil

Answer (score 0):

Check your **local.properties** file in your root project. And change it to something like this:

```
sdk.dir=F:/ANDROIDSDK
```

You need to remember that in Android Studio, **path** is using `/` instead of `\`.