# try to start AR android example project

Tags: android, android-augmented-reality

I try to run this test project [Android AR quickstart](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/quickstart)

I have message that SDK is not found.
I put ANDROID_HOME env.variable though I have the same  error.

My local.properties file in gradle scripts is as:

ndk.dir=G:\#Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle
sdk.dir=G:\#Android\Sdk

Is path in sdk.dir is written correctly?

(Actual path to sdk is G:#Android\sdk)

Comment: Which example project are you talking about? Please be more specific about your steps to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID\_HOME environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27620262/sdk-location-not-found-define-location-with-sdk-dir-in-the-local-properties-fil)