# How to fix "SDK location not found..."?

Tags: android, linux, react-native, ubuntu

after run `sudo react-native run-android`

echo error:

> SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.

after add sdk.dir in local.properties is work, but i want fix generaly.

in ~/.bashrc

`export ANDROID_HOME="$HOME/programs/android_sdk"
export PATH="$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools"
export PATH="$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools"`

but not work!
how can i fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID\_HOME environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27620262/sdk-location-not-found-define-location-with-sdk-dir-in-the-local-properties-fil)

Comment: not possible and not solutions

Comment: Here, hope it support U .....
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48155800/8850042

Answer (score 0):

Try adding like this

Add the following in ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bashrc.

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/share/android-sdk
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/build-tools/23.0.1:$PATH
```

Worked for me this way.Hope it works for you too !

Answer (score 0):

for windows os

The error message suggests that the `SDK` location could not be found in your system.   add the path to the `SDK` executable to your system's environment variables.
you can try adding the path to the `SDK` executable to your system's environment variables. You can do this by following these steps:

1. Open the Start menu and search for "Environment Variables".
2. Click on "Edit the system environment variables".
3. Click on the "Environment Variables" button.
4. Under "System Variables", scroll down and find the "Path" variable.
5. Click on "Edit".
6. Click on "New" and add the path to the `SDK` folder of the installation.vaiable name: `ANDROID_HOME` variable value: `C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk`.
7. Click on "OK" to close all windows.