# How to fix: A problem occurred configuring project

Tags: react-native, yarnpkg

I build a project in react-native and it works fine on my computer, but after change its location the problem starts to happen. I installed the package using "yarn add @react-native-community/async-storage"

I tried to npm install, re-install the component with yarm, and others.

```json
    "dependencies": {
        "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.4.2",
        "react": "16.8.3",
        "react-native": "0.59.9",
        "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.5.0",
        "react-redux": "^7.1.0",
        "redux": "^4.0.1"
    },
```

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':@react-native-community_async-storage'.

> SDK location not found. Define location with an ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable or by setting the sdk.dir path in your project's local properties file at '/Users/matheus/Desktop/TicTaeToe/android/local.properties'.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37002256/5027899. Have you tried this answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create a file in the android folder called **local.properties**

In this file write the path to your sdk, example:
**sdk.dir=C:\Users\ialluego\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk**

(ialluego is your username)

Comment: can you please add bit more related information for better understanding? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Basically its like You are building an apk without sdk , android sdk is required to build an app in react native and sdk`s path is located inside your system somewhere like

> C:\Users\NameOFYourSystem\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

So to do this you can create local.properties file in android folder of your app and map the sdk.dir= above path

thats it all it needs one line in locaal.properties

Answer (score -1):

this problem happened in windows because of slashes

in your project folder navigate to android and open local.properties file

replace

```
sdk.dir=C:\Users\\<userName>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
```

with

> `sdk.dir=C:\\Users\\<userName>\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk`

and it will work correctly