# Getting android studio error when run React native app in Linux

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, ubuntu

I have installed react native and Android in my Linux mint. I have created a project

```
react-native init <appName>
```

after that i ran this code in terminal

```
react-native run-android
```

I am getting error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> SDK location not found. Define location with an ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable or by setting the sdk.dir path in your project's local properties file at '/var/www/html/react/megaMillion/android/local.properties'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 0s
error Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
error Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

Can i know the problem. bcause i have tried a lot with this. Thank in advance.

Now getting this error.

```
info JS server already running.
info Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew app:installDebug)...
> Task :app:installDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'.
> com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: No connected devices!

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.4.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 2s
26 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 25 up-to-date
error Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
error Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

Please help me to install this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27620262/sdk-location-not-found-define-location-with-sdk-dir-in-the-local-properties-fil/27620622

Comment: The solution is directly in the error message: "SDK location not found. Define location with an ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable or by setting the sdk.dir path in your project's local properties file at '/var/www/html/react/megaMillion/android/local.properties'."

Comment: It is already defined. Still getting the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `ANDROID_HOME` to your path, add the following to your `.bashrc || .zshrc || .profile` file

```
# change $HOME to the path where you installed android Sdk
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Android/Sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
```

Then run

```
$ source ~/.bashrc || .zshrc || .profile
```

Comment: where is the file ?

Comment: in your home directory, open your terminal and type `ls -a`

Comment: run `echo $ANDROID_HOME` and tell me what you get

Comment: /home/ranjit/Android/Sdk

Comment: where did you install your android sdk?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195045/discussion-between-ranjit-and-junius-l).