# Build failed of react-native project

Tags: android, react-native

When i try to build a react-native project this error happens:

```
info Starting JS server...
info Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && gradlew.bat ap
p:installDebug)...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> SDK location not found. Define location with an ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment v
ariable or by setting the sdk.dir path in your project's local properties file a
t 'D:\COURSES\React Native - The Practical Guide\myFirstApp\android\local.proper
ties'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
error Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.

Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
error Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug. Run CLI with --verbose flag
for more details.
```

I can't run the project on Genymotion because of this problem .

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the path of the Android SDK in the **local.properties** file in the root of the react native project. I suggest you to take a look at the second answer of this question [SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27620262/sdk-location-not-found-define-location-with-sdk-dir-in-the-local-properties-fil)

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned in error message, there is no Android SDK installed. try install android SDK and ensure `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` has defined and pointed to the correct directory.

The simple way, try install [android studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/)

Comment: I installed android studio and this happened
```
> Configure project :app
Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3 in C:\Users\BEn
Hany\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3 not accepted.
Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 28 in C:\Users\BEn Hany\Ap
pData\Local\Android\Sdk\licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Platform 28 not accepted.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Comment: try run that adroid studio, also try to create new simple android studio, and run it