# How do I make an Android Chat-App with Android Studio and Typescript? [possibly with WebRTC and Websocket Server]

Tags: git, typescript, android-studio, github, .d.ts

Hope you are well! I am very inexperienced with coding, but here it goes. I am making a chat-roulette app (or chatting app) in Android Studio and following the tutorial-link with the following link from WebRTC: https://webrtc.ventures/2018/01/web...t-roulette-clone-using-kotlin-and-typescript/

I have carried out the typescript steps in the beginning, which worked successfully. But once I start using Android Studio, which is where I am having struggles, I see two ways of carrying out their tutorial:

1) To import or insert their codes that they have written in the boxes supported by GitHub, where they start to become red-coloured in my Android Studio 'main_activity'. So when I run the app, there are errors stating: "requiring top level declaration" or "expecting a qualified name". [Errors Shown in Red Colour When Following Steps (approach 1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56Krt.png)

OR

2) Downloading their source code. However, as the whole file is bigger than just the app, it does not allow me to run the app, where the "Run app" button is grey(transparent). [Errors Shown in Source Code (approach 2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPyzZ.png)

Additional information: When I tried to follow your steps of creating .ts files, I put them all in the same path directory. [Additional Information on My Project Path Directory (additional pic)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0onKm.png)

Could anyone here help me figuring out what the problems are? I look forward to hearing from you. Thanks for having read through my question,

Yours sincerely,

Ashbeck Henderson

In addition whilst I am waiting for this thread to be answered, I am will be working on: https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/11/finding-love-on-callroulette-an-android-studio-adventure.html
Maybe this one is simpler.

Not sure if images are embedded properly, but I hope you understand what I am having problems with nevertheless.

Comment: Please copy and paste error messages as text, see here why: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode Also please ask only one question at a time as you can only accept one answer. Feel free to create multiple questions.

Comment: The answer for your second question is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27620262/sdk-location-not-found-define-location-with-sdk-dir-in-the-local-properties-fil (The answer with the most upvotes)