# Build Of Android App From Commandline Fails

Tags: java, android

I am trying to build an android app from command line after installing the platform tools. but I am getting the following error

```
 SDK location not found. Define location with an ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable or by setting the sdk.dir path in your project's local properties file
```

IS the IDE necessary to build the app,or can we build it from the command line iteself?

Comment: Are you trying to create a "Hello World" app without Android Studio or building an existing app (i.e for a CI/CD system).

Comment: You can certainly build from the command line, but you have to have installed the SDK first...

Comment: I am trying to build an apk for an existing app without having to install the idea @MorrisonChang

Comment: See: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/variables

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID\_HOME environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27620262/sdk-location-not-found-define-location-with-sdk-dir-in-the-local-properties-fil)