# Can't start emulator on vs code for react native

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, react-native, android-emulator

I can't start the android emulator on vs code to run react-native. I already have an emulator in android studio. It shows

`` error Failed to launch emulator. Reason: No emulators found as an output of `emulator -list-avds`. ``
As a fresher to react-native, I don't know what to do.
Metro bundler is running well, But When enter `npx react-native run-android`

```
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 870 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...
info Starting JS server...
info Installing the app...
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
IOException: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-3.xml
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
IOException: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
IOException: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-1.xml
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
Failed to download any source lists!
IO exception while downloading manifest:
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

Comment: Could you please explain to us what step you've done so far? please look at this documentation https://reactnative.dev/docs/running-on-device. And make sure your  metro bundler is running on your terminal otherwise, hit `react-native start`

Comment: I just created the project and trying to run it.Metro Bundler also showing the error  `Failed to construct transformer:  Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported`

Comment: Did you try this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69692842/error0308010cdigital-envelope-routinesunsupported

Comment: with that link, I solved the error in the metro bundler. So Metro bundler is running well.  And the problem remaining is the emulator is not running...

Comment: The error while running `react-native run-android`  is that `error Failed to launch emulator. Reason: No emulators found as an output of `emulator -list-avds.`

Comment: You have to run your emulator first on android studio before running `yarn android`

Comment: I tried it but the output is the same error

Comment: Did you try to setup local properties on android? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27620262/sdk-location-not-found-define-location-with-sdk-dir-in-the-local-properties-fil? 
if yes, please try hit `react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res`

Comment: Hey, metro bundler is running well but can't start the emulator. when entering `npx 
 react-native run-android`  shows 
`java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved.
1  :Downgraded the node js
2  :Changed the `buildToolsVersion` and it work