# Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug React Native

Tags: react-native

Trying to launch new project and getting this error.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

  > SDK location not found. Define location with an ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable or by setting the sdk.dir path in your project's local properties file at '/home/mobii/android/local.properties'.

  - Try:

  > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
  > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
  > Run with --scan to get full insights.

  - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

  BUILD FAILED in 2s

  ```
  at makeError (/home/mobii/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/node_modules/execa/index.js:174:9)
  at /home/mobii/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/node_modules/execa/index.js:278:16
  at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
  at async runOnAllDevices (/home/mobii/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/runOnAllDevices.js:109:5)
  at async Command.handleAction (/home/mobii/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:192:9)
  ```

Comment: You have to set your Java SDK Path. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27620262/sdk-location-not-found-define-location-with-sdk-dir-in-the-local-properties-fil

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID\_HOME environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27620262/sdk-location-not-found-define-location-with-sdk-dir-in-the-local-properties-fil)

Comment: I tried adding a local.properties file -  in linux sdk.dir = /home/USERNAME/Android/Sdk
and didn't worked.

Comment: Try to put it in your system path variables