# android studio sdk not found exception

Tags: android, android-studio

An error saying "SDK location not found" occurred

I want the app to build

Comment: Please add more context about the error, like what is your operating system, which Android Studio version are you using, or if you already downloaded the SDK from the helper tool in Android Studio. You can also search for similar questions in stackoverflow like this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/48155800/5701750

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have SDK on your system

https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools

You can download SDK for your windows / Linux or Mac from this android official website.

Answer (score 0):

Open Android Studio

Go to Tools -> SDK Manager -> Check your Android SDK Location

If you have downloaded SDK at manual path then set that path in Android SDK's path here,

If not then check this path "C:\Users\YOUR_PC_NAME\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk" (AppData is a hidden folder) This path is the default download path when we install Android Studio